# Custom listener - Can't get reference to GUI instance

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm developing a plugin for custom network analysis which consist of:

- GUI class derived from AbstractVisualizer (recently changed superclass to AbstractJMeterGuiComponent to get rid of file panel)
- test element class derived from ResultsCollector

I've overriden a testStarted() method in test element class to do some initialization and then to start a separate thread which does the rest.

My problem is that I need to display some information on GUI of my plugin but I'm not able to get a reference to my GUI object to use it's methods. I need to do this  independently on events of receiving sample results thus I can't use method add(final SampleResult res).

In the beginnig I was sending GUI object reference to test element class in modifyTestElement method:

```
@Override
    public void modifyTestElement(TestElement element) {
        configureTestElement(element);
        NetProbe el = (NetProbe) element;

        //Passing GUI handle to TestElement for later status reporting
        if (el.getGuiHandle() == null) {
            el.setGuiHandle(this);
        }            
    }
```

This worked very well if I stored the reference in a static variable in the test element. But as I intend to add multiple instances of my new component to the test plan I had to make the variable non-static to have individual reference to each GUI class instance. And this is where the problem appears. I get NullPointerException if I do this.

I've done some investigation by using text interpretation of the test element objects and I found out that:

- when I create the test element in createTestElement method it is one instance
- when it is passed to modifyTestElement where GUI reference is sent to TE it is still the same instance
- when I try to call a method of GUI from the test element it is different (new?) instance -> thus the non-static variable which should store the GUI reference is empty
- when modifyTestElement is then called again it uses again the original instance

Could anyone please explain me where and why this new instance is created and how to get a reference to my GUI class object from test element object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's too long to post a good answer, but you could solve it with something like shared list of GUIs, which ResultsCollector accesses, but instead I suggest reconsidering the model and going back to typical JMeter model, where GUI refreshes itself independently, after querying some source of truth, and not some other component refreshes GUI. If you don't want to do it on `add`, you can have timer, or event/subscriber model, etc., so that ResultsCollector just collects data, while GUI either gets notified when new data is available, or queries the data periodically.

Comment: Thanks for reaction Kirill S.. I know my question is quite long but as the problem is specific I wanted to include all neccessary details which would have to be mentioned later anyway.

Comment: I tried to implement a static shared list of GUI-TE pairs which was initialized by 'modifyTestElement' of each instance. But it failed for the same reason - TE instance created by 'createTestElement' differs from the one which is then trying to post info to GUI so it is not found in the shared list.
The 'add' is useless as I mentioned before, but periodical querying from GUI sounds interesting. May you explain how/where to implement it in the GUI class? I think it must not block in any of the GUI methods.
Notifying GUI would be also fine, but how to do it if I have no reference ot it?